# Make Yasnippet insert characters before the key

Tags: latex, yasnippet

I want to create a snippet, which does the following:
When I write `. foo` it creates `A.B` while the cursor is in front of B.

I only found ways to insert text after the `key` and to delete text before, but not to insert text before the key. I suspect this can be done by some Emacs lisp, similarly to deleting characters in front, but I failed to find out how. How can I obtain the described behavior?

The reason I want this is, because I want to create a snippet, which puts an expression into LaTex math mode, i.e. I write `x` and want it to be put into math mode `\(x\)` by the snippet.
The goal is to then execute other context-sensitive (i.e. only working in math mode) manipulations of the character inside the snipped. For example, when I type `x⃗`, then the snipped should turn it into `\(\vec{x}\)`. In this case  ⃗ is the key of the snipped. I already have a snipped which turns `x⃗` into `\vec{x}`, and I only want it to also put it into maths mode. This is the reason, why I want a technique to put a `x` into `\(x\)` because my hope is, that then I am able to combine this with the snipped I already have to get the desired result.

Comment: If you don't mind selecting region, there is another small template package [TempEl](https://github.com/minad/tempel) that can wrap region and there are also general [templates](https://github.com/minad/tempel#template-file-format) for `latex-mode`.

Comment: Could give an example including what commands you run? Like (`I` is the position of the cursor): Buffer content is `xI`, I use `yas-expand` to expand the snippet (is x actually the key for your snippet? or can this be a whole formula?) and it should give me `\(xI\)`. This can most likely be achieved with a function as you can programmatically expand a snippet with elisp `(yas-expand-snippet (yas-lookup-snippet "block" 'org-mode))`. A function not using yasnippet is probably even easier to write.

Comment: The buffer content is `xI`, where x is not the key of my snipped, but instead it should be any char. I've edited my question to include some more context to, why I want this.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$0`, you can set a position within the snippet that the cursor will go to after the snippet is loaded to the buffer, for example

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: math mode
# key: m
# --
\\($0\\)
```

Will output your desired `\(` and `\)` then let you type in between

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is not quite what I want. I was aware of this functionality, but I want to type a character first, then afterwards execute the snipped which then turns the character into math mode. This is especially useful, because my aim is to then execute other context-sensitive (i.e. only working in math mode) manipulations of the character inside the snipped.